# C# - User defines which key-binds they wish to use for program

Tags: c#

I'm currently making a C# 2 player Rock paper scissors game and i'm stuck for what to do. 
Basically as it stands, the users enter which keys they would like for rock, paper and scissors. 
I have these keys stored in variables so the program remembers them. The issue is that I can't find or think of how the program then detects how these keys have been pressed afterwards when the game itself has initiated. 
I thought possibly enum's or storing them in an array possibly?

Not sure, Here's what i have so far.

```
    static bool winner = false;
    static string player1;
    static string player2;
    static ConsoleKeyInfo Rock1;
    static ConsoleKeyInfo Rock2; //variables for objects and players names etc
    static ConsoleKeyInfo Scissors1;
    static ConsoleKeyInfo Scissors2;
    static ConsoleKeyInfo Paper1;
    static ConsoleKeyInfo Paper2;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        do
        {
            PlayerChoosesNameAndKeys();
            game();                       //main game loop
        } while (winner == false);
    }

    static public void PlayerChoosesNameAndKeys()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Player {0} chooses there name:", i);
            if (i == 1)
            {
                player1 = Console.ReadLine();                            //players choose names
                Console.WriteLine("Player 1's name is: {0}", player1);
            }
            else
            {
                player2 = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Player 2's name is: {0}", player2);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Players now choose the keys they wish to represent the different objects");


        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} choose what key Rock is", player1);
                Rock1 = Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to confirm");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} choose what key Paper is", player1);
                    Paper1 = Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to confirm");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                if (i == 2)                                   //selection to decide what keybinds players want 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} choose what Key Sisscors is", player1);
                    Scissors1 = Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to confirm");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                if (i == 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} choose what key Rock is", player2);
                    Rock2 = Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to confirm");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                if (i == 4)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} choose what key Paper is", player2);
                    Paper2 = Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to confirm");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                if (i == 5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} choose what Key Sisscors is", player2);
                    Scissors2 = Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to confirm");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }  
        }

    static public void game()
    {

        int score1 = 0;
        int score2 = 0;
        int count = 1;
        //actual game 

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Round {0}", count);
            Console.WriteLine("Rock...");
            Console.WriteLine("Paper...");
            Console.WriteLine("Scissors...");
            Console.WriteLine("{0} input Object!: ",player1);

             ConsoleKeyInfo input = Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine();

            if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.Rock1)
            {

            }
        } while (score1 != 10 || score2 != 10);
    }
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Perhaps you should just include where your code is erroring out and not your entire code. It makes the job a lot easier for people trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply save user choices as character (for example `char Rock`); and then use `ConsoleKeyInfo.KeyChar`:

```
if (input.KeyChar == Rock)
{

}
```

for example:

```
char Rock = 'r'; // default value
Console.WriteLine("{0} choose what key Rock is", player1);
Rock = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
```

Or just check the insterted key with your saved key:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} choose what key Rock is", player1);
ConsoleKeyInfo Rock = Console.ReadKey();
```

and then:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo input = Console.ReadKey();
if (input.Key == Rock.Key)
{

}
```